# Array of Bitmap not initialized in Android

Tags: android, bitmap, bitmapimage

I am working with Bitmap in android.

In AsyncTask's doInBackgroud method I did the following code

```
protected Bitmap[] doInBackground(Object... params) {
        hMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, ArrayList<AssetBean>>();
        hMap = (ConcurrentHashMap<String, ArrayList<AssetBean>>) params[0];
        myKeyList = (CopyOnWriteArrayList<String>) params[1];
        if (Constants.DEBUG)
            Log.i("MyKeylist", myKeyList.toString()+"myKeyList size :"+myKeyList.size());

        myBitmap = new Bitmap[myKeyList.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < myKeyList.size(); i++) {

            String name = myKeyList.get(i);
            ArrayList<AssetBean> ab = hMap.get(name);
            AssetBean b = ab.get(0);
            File f = b.getThumbPath();
            Bitmap bitmap;
            if (null != f) {

                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
                if (bitmap != null)
                    myBitmap[i] = bitmap;
                else
                    myBitmap[i] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                            mContext.getResources(),
                            R.drawable.brokenicon_new);
            }

        }

        return myBitmap;
    }
```

from the above code the

```
myBitmap = new Bitmap[myKeyList.size()];
```

myBitmap assigned null and myKeyList.size() is not zero.

How can I resolve this?
Is I anything missed?

Answer (score 1):

> myBitmap assigned null

Because you just create `myBitmap` `Array` but not added data.

You need to convert your `ArrayList` to `Array` like

```
 myBitmap =myKeyList.toArray(new Bitmap[myKeyList.size()]);
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention the following. The same code working with Samsung Galaxy Tab but not in Samsung Nexus 4.

Comment: Its leads to ArrayStoreException